# Could not find com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dependencies

Im trying to include spinkit but when i build the project it gives me error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/ybq/Android-SpinKit/1.4.0/Android-SpinKit-1.4.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/ybq/Android-SpinKit/1.4.0/Android-SpinKit-1.4.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

i dont know why it is happening sudenly i previously used spinkit but dint give me any error like this but now when im trying to inlude it again this error comes up

Comment: did you add `mavenCentral()` ?

Comment: no becuase they said you have to implement this line only in gradle module app

Comment: yes i have checked build gradle there is mavenCentral() in repositories and in allprojects

Comment: ok i have tried with othere github dependency the same issue is happening dont know what to do i reinstalled android studio ut still the issue is going on

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Instead of adding maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in your project level gradle file add it in `settings.gradle`

In `settings.gradle`

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
```

this fixed my problem like you.

Comment: for latest project use => maven(uri("https://jitpack.io"))